# Add many calculated columns by grouping variables and then collapse df

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

We have student-level data with students specific grades and subjects attached to teachers in schools in districts.

```
student grade  subject  teacher  school  district female  poverty
1        4       Math     1        1        1       Yes      No
2        4       Math     1        1        1       Yes      No
3        4       Math     1        1        1        No      No
4        4       Math     2        1        1       Yes     Yes
5        4       Math     2        1        1       Yes     Yes
6        4       Math     3        1        1       Yes      No
7        4       Math     4        1        1        No     Yes
8        4       Math     5        1        1        No     Yes
9        4       Math     5        1        1        No     Yes
```

The data include over 700,000 rows for any given year and subject, spanning multiple grades and teachers in multiple districts and schools.

For every unique teacher in every grade + subject + school + district we need to

- (a) add columns that indicate what percent of students in his/her class are female, poor, etc., and
- (b) collapse the resulting dataframe into one with a single row per unique teacher 
  in every grade + subject + school + district

The resulting df would lok like ...

```
teacher  grade  subject  district  school  pct_fem  pct_poor  ...
1         4       Math     1           1     66.66     0      ...
2         4       Math     1           1    100.00     66.66  ...
```

and so on.

We have been doing it via plyr as in

```
ddply(df, .(teacher, grade, subject, district, school), transform, 
  n_students=length(unique(student)),
  n_fem=length(unique(student[female=="Yes"])), 
  pct_fem = (n_fem/n_students)*100)
```

However, this seems to take forever and often generates an error message to the effect that the code can't find n_fem or n_students.

If we write multiple ddply() statements, generating only one column at a time, then it works but that seems patently inefficient because we then have to merge these new columns into a new dataframe and then collapse this dataframe to a single record per teacher per grade, subject, district, and school.

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish what we want with these large datasets? Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Comment: Edit your question rather posting into comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function to be applied to each column within each group:

```
prop_Yes = function(x){
  tab = prop.table(table(factor(x,levels=c("Yes","No"))))
  tab[names(tab)=="Yes"]
}

g_vars = c("grade", "subject", "teacher", "school", "district")
p_vars = c("female", "poverty")
```

There are a few different ways to go from here:

**base R**

```
aggregate(DF[p_vars], DF[g_vars], prop_Yes)

  grade subject teacher school district    female poverty
1     4    Math       1      1        1 0.6666667       0
2     4    Math       2      1        1 1.0000000       1
3     4    Math       3      1        1 1.0000000       0
4     4    Math       4      1        1 0.0000000       1
5     4    Math       5      1        1 0.0000000       1
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(DF)[ , lapply(.SD, prop_Yes), by=g_vars, .SDcols=p_vars]

   grade subject teacher school district    female poverty
1:     4    Math       1      1        1 0.6666667       0
2:     4    Math       2      1        1 1.0000000       1
3:     4    Math       3      1        1 1.0000000       0
4:     4    Math       4      1        1 0.0000000       1
5:     4    Math       5      1        1 0.0000000       1
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by_(.dots=g_vars) %>% summarize_each_(funs(prop_Yes), p_vars)

  grade subject teacher school district    female poverty
  (int)   (chr)   (int)  (int)    (int)     (dbl)   (dbl)
1     4    Math       1      1        1 0.6666667       0
2     4    Math       2      1        1 1.0000000       1
3     4    Math       3      1        1 1.0000000       0
4     4    Math       4      1        1 0.0000000       1
5     4    Math       5      1        1 0.0000000       1
```